# Finding partial substrings within a string

Tags: algorithm, string, pattern-matching, substring

I have two strings which must be compared for similarity.  The algorithm must be designed to find the maximal similarity.  In this instance, the ordering matters, but intervening (or missing) characters do not.  Edit distance cannot be used in this case for various reasons.

The situation is basically as follows:

```
string 1: ABCDEFG
string 2: AFENBCDGRDLFG
```

the resulting algorithm would find the substrings `A`, `BCD`, `FG`

I currently have a recursive solution, but because this must be run on massive amounts of data, any improvements would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post a description of your current, recursive solution?

Comment: Do you have a language for this?

Comment: Is it just me, or is this NP-hard?

Comment: @Peter: The reason I removed the `substring` tag was that substrings are always consecutive. What you want is a subsequence which need not be consecutive.

Comment: @codaddict. OP wants a sequence of substrings, not a subsequence.

Comment: The recursive solution is as follows: take the first character in string 1, use it as a substring and search in string 2.
If the substring is found, increase the substring size to the first two characters of string 1, and search string 2
repeat until a substring is no longer found
move to the next character in string 1, and the search string pointer up by one character.
There's a little bit of optimization going on in it, but the solution is still a high order polynomial time or worse (I haven't done a full analysis on the time yet, but suffice to say its quite slow)

Comment: One of the problems I'm currently having is that each "character" I search for is actually an 8 character string, so instead of "A" i'm actually searching for "pushmov " or "mov jnz ", and I haven't found a way to simplify it within the program.

Comment: Isn't "E" also a common substring here?

Comment: E would not be in the substring list because the ordering matters, and there is a better match using the other characters.  I've also realized the solution I had above is terribly broken, and using a modified version of that method (to correct it) would cause the algorithm to run in exponential time.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at your sole example it looks like you want to find longest common **subsequence**. 
Take a look at [LCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

> Is it just me, or is this NP-hard? – David Titarenco (from comment)

If you want LCS of arbitrary number of strings its NP-hard. But it the number of input strings is constant ( as in this case, 2) this can be done in polynomial time.

Comment: This isn't right. given OP's example input, it would return 'ABCDFG'

Comment: @Aaron: You'll have to modify the algorithm a bit to find the actual substring that contributed to the answer. But the basic idea remains very much the same.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into modifying an LCS algo